# angularjs ng-blur when something when form field is empty

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Below is my angular js code:

```html
       <div class = "large" ng-class="{'large active':hasFocus==true,'large':hasFocus==false}">
  <label class="label">Username</label>
        <input class="field" name="username" type="text" ng-model="username" 
        ng-click="hasFocus=true" ng-blur="hasFocus=false"></div>
```

on click and on click-away, the css classes are getting changed. 
How do i add logic to check is no text is entered then only switch class?
If some text is entered then the class should no change.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a check to the "username" field in the ng-class:

```
<div class="large" ng-class="{'large active':hasFocus==true ,'large':hasFocus==false && username}">
        <label class="label">Username</label>
        <input class="field" name="username" type="text" ng-model="username" 
        ng-click="hasFocus=true" ng-blur="hasFocus=false"></div>
```

The important part is 'hasFocus == false && username'. You can check username has text or not by just writing "&& username" to your logic statement --> this will return true if username has text, and will return false if it doesn't.

Comment: Maybe add "&& !username" to the "hasFocus==true" statement?